# Is there a standard way to create a sharable objects with a custom destructor?

Tags: c++, std

Is there a standard type that looks like a `std::shared_ptr` in all aspects *except* actually pointing to anything?

I'm looking for something that's copyable/movable, typesafe, ref-counted, easily constructible with a custom deleter.

I just don't need it to point to anything.

I have been using `std::make_shared((int*)1, [](auto) { /* do stuff */ })`, but I really don't need the `int`. Maybe I'm missing something, but I see overly-verbose boilerplate all over the place for doing precisely this.

Comment: So you want to create an object that is shareable and once all instances of it are destroyed then it runs some sort of action?

Comment: @NathanOliver in `std::`, yes. even `boost::` will suffice.

Comment: Could you please provide use case for that behaviour? I think that perhaps what you are looking for is just a destructor in a custom class? You could share the object and as long as it is just a single instance the task will be executed once (that means just delete copy operations on this object and pass it by reference / move it)

Comment: yes, i could create a destructor in a custom class, but like i said above i'm trying to avoid 'overly-verbose boilerplate'.

Answer (score 3):

How about this? Same use of a shared_ptr that doesn't point to anything but with a custom constructor that takes any function (with no arguments).

```cpp
class shared_destructible : public std::shared_ptr<void> {
public:
    template<typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>>>
    shared_destructible(F f): std::shared_ptr<void>(nullptr, [f](void*){
        f();
    }) {}
};
```

Example use

```cpp
int main() {
    int test = 2023;
    shared_destructible a([test]() { std::cout << test << std::endl; });
    auto b = a;
    auto c = a;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2023
```

Comment: ah, i didn't think you could pass `nullptr`, i could have sworn i tried that and it didn't work. you can use `void` instead of `void*`, too: `auto a = std::shared_ptr<void>(nullptr, [test](auto){ std::cout << test << std::endl; });`

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr` can give you the "shared" part, and you can write your own custom class for the destruction part. In full generality (if you want the lambda parameter like in your example),

```
class Destructible {
private:
  std::function<void()> impl;
public:
  Destructible(const std::function<void()>& impl) : impl(impl) {}
  ~Destructible() {
    impl();
  }
};
```

Then the type you're looking for is called `std::shared_ptr<Destructible>`. You can construct one with `std::make_shared<Destructible>([]() { ... });`

Comment: why would I need that? `shared_ptr` already has custom destructor support. the `(int*)` example I have in the question already does what I need and allocates less. I'm looking for something in the std library that doesn't even require the additional pointer or allocation.

Comment: @Spongman while there are some memory wasted (32 vs 16 bytes), it still uses a single allocation: std::function does not do dynamic allocations for trivial function pointers, makes_shared makes sure that Destructible and control block are allocated together: a single allocation.

Comment: sure, but what does your answer buy me beyond what my `(int*)` example does? except more boiler-plate, which i'm trying to avoid.